# Views... no format options in Fields->User?

Tags: views, 6, media

In any Field using the USER type there are no format options.  I'm making a user_picture view and want to use the image cache option.  But, at the bottom of any Field (pertaining to USER) where Format* usually shows up, it's not there.  Any ideas why?  Thank you.

Also, Format* works for nodes/content types.  So, it's installed and working functionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the user image is not a field unlike images attached to nodes. Views is using the field formatter that applies to fields and the way they are themed to allow you to select how you want to theme the field. This functionality doesn't work for properties like the user image.

The same goes for the say the node type. You can't select how to display the node type.

The easiest thing to do, is properly get the raw url and with theming turn it into the image with the image cache preset you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried the old <?php  print theme('imagecache', 'user_picture', $account->picture, $alt, $title,  $attributes); ?> in my comment.tpl.php but it won't render.  I even tried just: <?php print $account -> picture ?> and that would't render.  Any ideas on this?  Thank you.

Comment: @Graham Sounds like the account does not have a profile picture or it hasn't been loaded, try doing a user_load on inspect the $account variable.